# Can't edit views even though I have admin rights. Says user not authorized. Help me understand please

Tags: views

I am working on my college website and the professor created an admin account for me. I have been able to do pretty much everything on this website but it won't let me edit any Views which is the main thing I am supposed to work on. Yes, I am beginner in Drupal, so please be nice. What could be the reason for me not being allowed to edit views? Should I talk to my IT helpdesk?

Comment: Ask your professor if they gave you the "administer views" permission (or if you have access to the permissions page, make sure at least one of the roles assigned to your account has those permissions)

Comment: Thanks Clive. But when I filtered the list of users in People for "administer views" permission, my username does show in the filtered list along with my professor and another student developer.

Comment: Permissions are at /admin/people/permissions - somewhat ironically, you need the "administer users" permission to access it, which you may or may not have. If not, someone with admin access will need to grant you either "administer users" or "administer views" to continue

Comment: I have dropped the admin an email regarding that. Hopefully he can sort this out soon. Thanks a lot for your help.